# Can we create a single app for iOS and tvOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, tvos, xcode10

I got a new project to start, but I have confusion before start the project , Can we create a single app for both iOS and tvOS

My Project will be for iphone/ipad and TvOS and also working for both modes portrait and landscape.

I tried but getting links for starting new project with tvOS. I also getting something about adding new target for tvOS but not exactly very clearly I understand what I have to do?

Please help me to start this project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create one project for iOS and tvOS application and share code between each other.

You need to create two targets, one for iOS and one for tvOS. 
If you want to distinguish part of the code in one file you can use conditional compilation statements: `#if os(iOS)` or `#if os(tvOS)`